# php + curl simple post

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to make automatic register script with curl.

I have html form:

```
<form method="post" action="/register/submit" autocomplete="off" id="js-register-form">
<input type="hidden" name="__csrf_token" value="28030357" />
<input name="nick" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" class="form-control" />
<input name="pass" type="password" size="15" maxlength="15" class="form-control" />
<input name="sex" type="radio" value="V" /> vyras </label>
<input name="sex" type="radio" value="M" /> moteris </label>

<select name="age_day" class="form-control">
<option>Diena</option>
<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>                    
</select>

<select name="age_month" class="form-control">
<option>Mėnuo</option>
<option value="1">Sausis</option><option value="12">Gruodis</option></select>

<select name="age_year" class="form-control">
<option>Metai</option>
<option>2001</option><option>2000</option><option>1999</option>                   </select>

<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="15" maxlength="50" class="form-control" />

<select name="city_id" class="form-control"><option value="">Miestas</option><option value="1340915">Akmenė</option><option value="1341068">Alytus</option><option value="1341242">Anykščiai</option><option value="1341276">
</select>

<button type="submit" title="Registruotis" class="btn btn-signup js-register-form-submit">Registruotis</button>
</form>
```

and this is my curl script, but it doesn't work. What s wrong with it?:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://login.com....html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "__csrf_token=28030357&nick=pixelis98722&pass=qwerty&sex=V&age_day=12&age_month=04&age_year=2000&email=pimlalalal8784555@gmail.com&city_id=1343628"); 

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

// further processing ....
if ($server_output == "OK") { echo"gerai"; } else { echo "bad"; }
?>
```

but doesn't work. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: what's the error, why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: `__csrf_token` will ultimately change and is held in session serverside, so whatever value you use will not be valid for multiple requests. your need to scrape it everytime and use session persistence in the curl request.

Comment: __csrf_token doesn't chage.

Comment: have heard of ajax ? that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
function httpPost($url,$params)
{
    $postData = '';
    //create name value pairs seperated by &
    foreach($params as $k => $v)
    {
        $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&';
    }
    rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

### This is the final answer. Try anyone. Both works.

```
<?php
$a=$_POST['__csrf_token'];
$b=$_POST['nick'];
$c=$_POST['pass'];
$d=$_POST['sex'];
$e=$_POST['age_day'];
$f=$_POST['age_month'];
$g=$_POST['age_year'];
$h=$_POST['email'];
$i=$_POST['city_id'];



$url = 'http://login.com....html';
$postData = array();
$postData['a'] = $a;
$postData['b'] = $b;
$postData['c'] = $c;
$postData['d'] = $d;
$postData['e'] = $e;
$postData['f'] = $f;
$postData['g'] = $g;
$postData['h'] = $h;
$postData['i'] = $i;

$parameters=json_encode($postData);

$headers = array(    "Accept-Encoding: gzip",
    "Content-Type: application/json");


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at [http_build_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to replace that loop

Comment: Did you try my answer?? @user2289809